# Running python3.8.2 in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run python3.8.2 with Ubuntu20.04.
I successfully installed python3.8.2 and velocyto, then via `velocyto --help` command I checked that the package has been successfully installed.

```
xxx@DESKTOP-39OCRLB:/usr/local/lib/python3.8$ velocyto --help
```

However since I want to use velocyto within python3.8 (not in Ubuntu terminal), I executed python3.8 via:

```
xxx@DESKTOP-39OCRLB:/usr/local/lib/python3.8$ python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  1 2021, 18:47:06) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and I successfully import velocyto without any error via:

```
import velocyto as vcy
```

But when I run `velocyto --help`, I bumped into NameError.

```
velocyto --help
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'velocyto' is not defined
```

How can I normally run velocyto within python3.8 (from Ubuntu)?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that Ubuntu 20.04 comes with [Python 3.8.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3) preinstalled? I'm not sure if that's important, but it might be part of your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported it as `vcy`, not `velocyto`. However, if you do `vcy --help`, you're going to get another NameError saying that `help` is not defined, because `velocyto --help` is a shell command, not a Python command.

You can simply go ahead and start using it. For example, [the tutorial says you can try this](https://velocyto.org/velocyto.py/tutorial/analysis.html):

```
vlm = vcy.VelocytoLoom("YourData.loom")
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! Okay, I get it now. Since I just started from scratch, sorry for my goofy question! Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Python is expecting valid Python statements at the `>>>`  prompt.

Apparently `velocyto` provides both a CLI a command to be executed from the shell and a Python library that can be used from Python code.

Quit the Python interpreter and type `velocyto --help` at your shell prompt to use the CLI.

I don't know how to use the Python library, but it appears to be well documented.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. The OP tried to run `velocyto --help` at a Python prompt. I explained how to run it at a shell prompt.

Comment: I think it's because OP wrote *"I want to use velocyto within python3.8 (not in Ubuntu terminal)"* [meaning shell]